# eigenvalues of $g(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A\in M_n(F)$ and let $c_1,\dots,c_n$ be eigenvalues of $A$. Prove that for each polynomial $g(x) \in F[x]$, eigenvalues of $g(A)$ are $g(c_1), \dots g(c_n)$. (Hint: triangulate $A$)

I don't have any idea to solve this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As in the hint, triangulate $A$, say $B$. (Note that this is only possible when the characteristic polynomial of $A$ splits over $F$. It's called Schur's theorem) Then, $g(B)$ is upper triangular and the diagonal terms are $g(B_{ii})$. Hence $det(XI-g(A))=det(XI-g(B))=(X-g(B_{11}))...(X-g(B_{nn}))=(X-g(c_1))...(X-g(c_n))$. First equality holds since $g(QAQ^{-1})=Qg(A)Q^{-1}$ where $Q$ is an invertible matrix.